# How to temporarily activate a virtualenv during a non-python debug session in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, virtualenv, vscode-debugger

So... you know those times when you are explaining your problem to another person and suddenly come to the answer?  This is one of those times.  Below is my original post, just moments away from being submitted, when I had an idea that turned out to fix the issue!  Read on...

---

I am working on an Electron-based project that I debug in VSCode. Part of that code spawns a couple external services written in Python. Those services just moved from Python 2.7 to Python 3.7, and I have a virtualenv set up for this purpose (I'm working on Ubuntu 16, where 2.7 is still needed, so I'm hesitant to remap `python` and `pip` to the newer version).

The problem is that I need a way to activate the virtualenv at the start of a debug session, as if electron had been started inside a bash shell (I activate the virtualenv in my .bashrc).  So my question is:  How can I activate a virtualenv during a debug session?

For completeness, here's my current launch configuration:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Electron Shell",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/dist",
            "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/dist/node_modules/electron/dist/electron",
            "runtimeArgs": ["app.js", "--remote-debugging-port=9222"],
            "protocol": "inspector",
        },
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Attach to Electron Shell",
            "port": 9222,
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
            "timeout": 30000
        }
    ],
    "compounds": [
        {
            "name": "Debug Angular In Electron Shell",
            "configurations": [
                "Attach to Electron Shell",
                "Launch Electron Shell",
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer, it turns out is to just do what the `activate` script is doing: modify `PATH` and unset `PYTHONHOME`.  Like so:

```
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Electron Shell",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/dist",
            "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/dist/node_modules/electron/dist/electron",
            "runtimeArgs": ["app.js", "--remote-debugging-port=9222"],
            "protocol": "inspector",
            "env": {
                "PATH": "/path/to/virtualenv/folder/bin:${env:PATH}",
                "PYTHONHOME": null
            }
        },
```